# What are the L1?

Tags: the-thousand-worlds, nightflyers

Started watching the new show *Nightflyers* and I'm hooked. I'm a bit confused at what the L1 are? Are they natural? Genetically modified?

Reading up about the show, I saw that it was an adaptation of George RR Martin's novella. I then did a bit of digging and found out that George wrote a few novellas in the 1980's and that all the stories are from the same universe.

Does he mention how the L1 are made? Mother nature or some lab experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### L are psychics - telepaths and empaths.

They have the ability to read thoughts and emotions and project images directly into other people's mind. Unfortunately, those abilities are poorly controlled, which might cause a tragedy like in the case of the shuttle Luna 71, where a little girl, an L-1 (the strongest in the three levels category) accidentally started reading people's fear of flight, amplified it and sent back... which created a feedback loop, panic increased to the point when people started killing each other.

While their origins are unknown, it is most likely a natural phenomenon - the Luna 71 case looks like an honest accident, the existing Ls are hunted and isolated and finally, we know that

> Dr. Agatha

is also a low level "L", that was able to live normally by chemically suppressing her abilities